# ListView ScrollViewer smaller than ListView height

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scroll

I have a ListView in my app (WPF C# .NET Core)

For example, if ListView height is 800, how i can set the ListView ScrollViewer height to 600 ?
Like this Photo:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocKoo.png)

(The main ListView VerticalAlignment *(ListView Bubble Messages)* is Stretched but the Scrollviewer height is smaller than ListView)

**Note**: if the value of Scrollviewer set to 0, the item of ListView must be Visible (Item It should not be under the TopBar panel)

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are trying to do. What have you tried? Can you post your XAML?

Comment: The DISCORD's vertical Scroll is just like an ordinary Scroll. It becomes Smaller automatically when `ScrollViewer` Content keep adding. Just like `Wpf Scroll` It automatically becomes smaller when no of items in it are are large.